# Confused as to why rspec is suddenly showing me so much information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

just a quick question about something I am probably overlooking.  I am going through Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial and (seemingly) out of nowhere, my rspec tests are spitting out a lot more information.  For example:

```
Started GET "/signup" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-03 12:36:30 -0800
Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 7.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
.
```

and for simple tests:

```
(0.4ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
.   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
.   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
```

Just looking for a way to make the test output a bit less verbose, so that I just see the ....F.. format with any errors/failures.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you recently set your config.logger to use STDOUT or something to that effect? Those lines are coming from the log, and generally get appended to the development.log file.

Comment: nope, I haven't changed any config files or log files or anything like that.

Comment: post your `spec_helper.rb` `.rspec`

Comment: [spec_helper.rb](http://pastebin.com/W10bs2VT)  and my .rspec just has "--colour" and nothing else

Comment: just to clarify my last comment, .rspec has the "--colour" and the spec_helper.rb is a link to a pastebin of the file

Comment: 1. This line `require 'rubygems'` confuses me (I have never met this line in spec_helper). 2. You setup configs twice: into `Spork` block and after it (from line 86..end) - I think it is enough to define it once - in Spork block.

Comment: Good call, I cleaned both of those issues up, however that didn't fix any of the output issues.  Here's the updated [spec_helper](http://pastebin.com/YvV19n2s)

Answer (score 2):

Do you happen to have the gem `rails_12factor` installed? It's often used in conjunction with deployment on Heroku.

If so, then I suppose the respective entry in your Gemfile looks like:

```
gem 'rails_12factor'
```

Just change it to the following and the additional output will disappear when running `rspec`:

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```